# Atualizar o banco de dados pelo SQL PHP

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos

Pessoal estou com dificuldade em atualizar o meu banco de dados para diminuir o peso em 1 kg. Qualquer ajuda eu agradeço. O código é o seguinte:

```
<?php
    class Aluno{
        public $nome;
        public $endereco;
        public $peso;
        public $altura;

            function __construct($nome, $endereco, $peso, $altura, $imc, $programa) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
            $this->endereco = $endereco;
            $this->peso = $peso;
            $this->altura = $altura;
            $this->imc = $imc;
            $this->programa = $programa;
            $this->imc = $this->calcularIMC();

            $this->peso = $this->calcularPeso();

      if ($this->imc<17) {$this->programa = "de ganho de peso.";
      }
      elseif ($this->imc>30) {$this->programa = "de perda de peso.";
      }
      else {$this->programa = "de manutenção do peso.";
      }


}

    function calcularPeso() {return round(($this->peso - 1),2);}

    function calcularIMC() {return round(($this->peso)/($this->altura*$this->altura),2);}



}
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "academia");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($conexao))
    {
        echo "Não conectado!<br>";
    }

    else {
        mysqli_query($conexao, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        echo "Conectado!</br></br>";
    }

    $listagem = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM aluno");

    while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($listagem)) {

        $alunoTemp = new Aluno($linha['nome'], $linha['endereco'], $linha['peso'], $linha['altura'], $linha['imc'], $linha['programa']);

        $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE aluno SET peso = peso WHERE nome=nome");  
}   

?>
```

Comment: A dificuldade é um erro ou resultado não esperado? poderia descrever melhor.

Comment: Se estiver tendo algum erro, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/53578/edit) sua pergunta e adicione essa informação.

Comment: Você quer passar os valores do objeto aluno no update? passe as respectivas propriedades, use aspas simples para valores em campo de texto ou use prepared statements.

Comment: troca o peso = peso por peso = {$alunoTemp->peso} e faz o mesmo no where, e, se eu fosse vc atualizava pelo id ao inves do nome

Answer (score 1):

Na real você não esta alterando os dados com essa query, ela vai atualizar todos os registros peso por ele mesmo

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE aluno SET peso = peso WHERE nome=nome");
```

Você tem que substituir os valores que quer atualizar como

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE aluno SET peso = {$alunoTemp->peso} WHERE nome=\"{$alunoTemp->nome}\"");
```

Comment: Dependendo da [configuração](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html) aspas duplas `"` tem o efeito de `\` `

Comment: Fiz a correção devida, porém quando imprimo, sai apenas as informações do primeiro aluno, segue o final da codificação: 
        $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE aluno SET peso = {$alunoTemp->peso} WHERE nome=\"{$alunoTemp->nome}\""); 
  echo "O aluno $alunoTemp->nome, que reside em $alunoTemp->endereco 
  com o peso de $alunoTemp->peso kg  e altura $alunoTemp->altura m, tem o IMC = $alunoTemp->imc 
  deverá fazer um programa $alunoTemp->programa</br>";